# C# - Title Bar "X" does not close the program AND form switching

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I have a Visual C# project using windowsforms that does not exit when the X is clicked on any form OTHER than the first form. I think this may have something to do with my form switching?

Currently, I have a Template.CS which is exactly what it sounds like. All of my usage forms extend this by:

```
public partial class Welcome : ADL.template
```

Then, I switch between forms by invoking this method:

```
    public static void formSwitch(Form in_form, Form out_form)
    {
        in_form.Hide();
        out_form.Show();          
    }
```

Called by:

```
Program.formSwitch(this, new frmUserInput());
```

What i think is happening here is, the X is closing the Form NOT the application because the starting form is Hidden, not closed. Is there a better way for me to switch between forms?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to overwrite the close function of your form to close the application from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well before answering your question, I should point out that `Hide` doesn't actually close your form, it only (as the name implies) hides it. So as time goes on, you'll keep piling on forms until you either run out of GDI objects or out of memory, either way you'll crash.

You are kind of correct about the reason why your application isn't closing though: even though you close the current form, *all your other forms are still loaded* so your application won't end.

To fix this, the best way would be to actually close your forms when you don't need them anymore. You won't even have to add any code to close your application then.

Now if you don't want to do that for whatever reason, you can always just call `Application.Exit`. I strongly discourage you to pursue this "solution" though.

**Edit**: as for a possible solution, you could change **Program.cs** to something like:

```
static class Program
{
  static Form NextForm=new frmLogin();   // or whatever your first form is
  static public void SetNext(Form next) { NextForm=next; }
  static void Main()
  { 
    while(NextForm!=null)
    {
      Form _next=NextForm;
      NextForm=null;      // so it closes at the end
      Application.Run(NextForm);
    }
  }
}
```

And then your `formSwitch` would become:

```
public static void formSwitch(Form in_form, Form out_form)
{
    Program.SetNext(out_form);
    in_form.Close();
}
```

It looks weird because your workflow is weird for a Windows program. This is more the workflow of a 1970 FORTRAN program running in DOS.

Comment: Blindy, thanks! Thats my problem though. in the formSwitch function, if I change Hide to Close, the application exits. What is a better way to go about switching forms?

Comment: Thanks blindy, much appreciated. Trying it now.

As for my work flow, what would be a better way of doing things? Using 1 form and removing/adding elements?

Comment: @Blindy: +1 for FORTRAN reference. @coderego: Using a single form is the 'normal' way to write Windows applications. Whether you add/remove elements (Panels), or use modal dialogs is up to you.

Comment: @coderego, a wizard dialog comes to mind, with back and forward buttons, as long as it's a clear, finite process. An even better way would be using a grid of some sorts and letting the user populate all the data at the same time. It depends on what exactly your app is doing, you didn't explain its function.

Comment: It is a wizard type program. Multiple steps, each of which takes user input, does some under-the-hood work, gives feedback and asks for more input.

Comment: @coderego, that's what makes it a dos workflow, the asking for more information one bit at a time part. Try to redo your interface so the user can enter it all from the beginning, even if it updates itself as he's entering it.

Answer (score 0):

The default Windows Forms application behaviour is: the application is closed when the MAIN window is closed.

The main window is the first one you've created. When you called `Hide()` on this window, it is rendered invisible (but still exists). So, closing the second window doesn't close the application.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought the problem was. Whats a better way to handle form switching then? If I change the Hide() to a Close() in that function, the program exits!

Comment: As suggested above, put `Application.Exit()` into the second form's `OnClose` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the code in the `~/Program.cs` file as the following:

```
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form f = new Form();
        f.Show();

        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

This way, the application wont close until you call `Application.Exit()` exclusivly.